# Hibernate doesn't correctly handle linked @ManyToOne entities during the deleting the parent entity

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one

There is a parent entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Vehicle extends BaseEntity {
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id")
    private List<Record> records;
}
```

and there is a child entity with InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Record extends BaseEntity {
  @ManyToOne
  @JsonIncludeProperties({"id"})
  private Vehicle vehicle;
}
```

When I try to get all vehicles, it will be ok.
When I try to delete any vehicle, there will be an error **"relation "record" does not exist"**.
A Hibernate log:

```
Hibernate: select v1_0.id,v1_0.name,v1_0.vin from vehicle v1_0
Hibernate: select v1_0.id,v1_0.name,v1_0.vin from vehicle v1_0 where v1_0.id=?
Hibernate: update record set vehicle_id=null where vehicle_id=?
```

How can I help Hibernate use the right tables?